# RightToLeft languages supporting in the TdxRichEditControl

Tags: delphi, devexpress

In an application that often uses TdxRichEditControl, support for Near Eastern languages should be included at the client's request. How to do it ? In other controls (TEdit, TcxEdit, TcxRichEdit), everything works correctly without additional settings. The problem is only in TdxRichEditControl. Input and display are mirrored when I type .

I type in the Hebrew language and the text is displayed left to right, even though it should be right to left

Comment: Better ask DevExpress support.

Comment: @DelphiCoder You say: *Better ask DevExpress support.* Why is that? Do you think that nobody else can answer? Or do you just want to divert people away from SO?

Comment: Is the text correct, but line is left-adjusted ? Or is each character placed on the right-hand side of the next (rendering text meaningless). Can you type correctly in Notepad or similar ?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Because they have very good support for their components.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Because DevEx has well-staffed support forums, and SO should be the **last resort** after all other avenues have been researched. The DevEx forums are clearly an avenue of research for this issue. Also, support for the DevEx controls in their forum is free for registered users.